# Is Padding a field a good choice for MySQL Index?

Tags: mysql, indexing

If you have a MySQL table with a very large number of rows that includes a variable length field that is often used in `WHERE` or `ORDER BY` clauses, and it is infrequent that `INSERTS` or `UPDATES` are made, then it would be a good candidate for using an index on the field.

However, from what I could find on the topic, it seems MySQL doesn't handle variable length fields very quickly (compared to fixed length fields) when you index them in this manner.  So, I was wondering if it would make sense to left pad the column's rows with empty strings to force all of them to some fixed maximum length.  Would this make any sense at all?  Or am I just over thinking this?

Comment: Good question. I've voted to migrate it to http://dba.stackexchange.com, as it might get better answers there.

Comment: If you're thinking about padding a variable length field to a common fixed maximum length... then why wouldn't you just make it a fixed length field?

Comment: @AlexHowansky Maybe it's lost in translation, but the idea is to pad it to use a fixed length field instead of the alternative (not padding and using variable length).

Comment: Let me rephrase -- if the the field is defined as variable length and you want to pad it so that it emulates a fixed length field, they why wouldn't you simply make it a fixed length field in the first place?

Comment: @user17753 I think what Alex is getting at is that you don't need to do any padding yourself.  Just use a fixed length data type and put in whatever length of data (up to the maximum) that you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After consulting the manual some more, I realize this is a "feature" already baked into MySQL:

> The length of a CHAR column is fixed to the length that you declare
>   when you create the table. The length can be any value from 0 to 255.
>   When CHAR values are stored, they are right- padded with spaces to the
>   specified length. When CHAR values are retrieved, trailing spaces  are
>   removed.